# SVG text shifted on Edge and IE

Tags: svg, text, microsoft-edge

I have isolated a case where SVG text is shifted only on Microsoft browsers (EDGE & IE)

```
<svg width="360" height="186" viewBox="0 0 120 64" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <text font-size="72" font-family="Arial" fill="#ff2204" x="0" y="62" text-anchor="middle">
    <tspan x="50%" dy="0">test</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to make the text centered as in other browsers?

Here's the sample code in [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qyhfesrk/7/)

Comment: I will but if you have an explanation of the different behaviour, then please go ahead and post an answer too

Comment: I have a Mac, so that's going to be tricky.

Comment: Alright, then my best guess if that other browsers collapse whitespaces in some way. But then why didn't the whitespaces before the `tspan` cause an issue on Edge? I'm just glad I stumbled upon this fix by pure luck

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#WhiteSpace

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that. Edge follows the `default` case in all but the strip trailing space step, which makes removing spaces in the markup the only cross-browser solution for now! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the whitespace between `</tspan>` and `</text>` resolves the issue

```
<svg width="360" height="186" viewBox="0 0 120 64" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <text font-size="72" font-family="Arial" fill="#ff2204" x="0" y="62" text-anchor="middle">
    <tspan x="50%" dy="0">test</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyhfesrk/9/)